# How to add live video streaming to a website?

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, flashmedialiveencoder

.Hi everyone! I am looking forward to create a website with a live video streaming feature.
I have done some research and read about some applications including Flash Media Live Encoder.
Can anyone please guide me on how to start with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a few live videos on your website, the solution is quite simple, Flash Media Live Encoder plus Flash Media Server are suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends from your requirements.
Do you need live streaming for big event or small event (what is your bandwidth)?
Do you need to stream to different devices (desktop+mobile)?
Do you have to stream your desktop/webcam or high quality camera feeds through capture cards?
Are you flexible with different Operative Systems?

Your question is too general. [FMLE](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html) + FMS is a good solution, but [FMS can be expensive](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family/buying-guide-pricing.html).
Try to have a look also to [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/pricing).